# ¿Qué antónimo de "inserción" se puede usar en informática?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática, antónimos

En el mundo de la informática, cuando estoy añadiendo algo en algún lugar digo que hago una *inserción*, tras lo cual decimos que se ha *insertado*. Por tanto, ambas frases serían válidas:

> XXX ha sido **insertado** correctamente.
>
> La **inserción** de XXX ha sido correcta.

Cuando en lugar de añadir lo que hacemos es eliminar, decimos que:

> YYY ha sido **eliminado** correctamente.

Sin embargo, ¿cuál podría ser el nombre que designara la acción de eliminar? Lo siguiente me suena mal:

> La **eliminación** de YYY ha sido correcta.

Me inclino a pensar que puede existir algo como *eliminaje*. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Sí, eliminación me parece correcto. No veo el problema...

Comment: "Borrado" se suele utilizar bastante también.

Comment: @Joze debo ser yo que estoy cargado de cuentos... Qué mal me suena a mi. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Fuera de la informática, el antonimo de inserción es extracción. Por otro lado, enfocados en el mundo informático, inserción es el opuesto directo de eliminación como bien deduces. Por ejemplo, si hablamos de operaciones sobre una base de datos, el opuesto de insertar o añadir un registro, sería eliminar o borrar el mismo y no extraerlo.

Comment: @Joze pues de todo lo dicho en esta pregunta me quedo con tu comentario. Si quieres, añádelo como respuesta para que pueda aceptarla : )

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar *extraer, extracción*.

[DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOFmHUL)

> Extraer 1. tr. sacar (‖ poner algo fuera de donde estaba).

Es también la palabra usada en los sistemas operativos al [descomprimir archivos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8crn4.jpg)

Comment: +1 Sí, extracción es ideal. Tiene un significado más sutil que eliminación para nuestro caso.

Comment: No, en informática extraer no implica borrar el original. Justamente en el ejemplo que pones de descompresión de archivos cuando se dice *extraer* el archivo sigue existiendo en el original comprimido.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @rsanchez. A mí extraer no me connota eliminación (no sé si es correcto el verbo *connotar* :P)

Comment: @rsanchez Sí puede ser, pero no hay que tomarlo literalmente, es el menos peor de los términos. Si miras la versión en español de Winrar o Winzip está escrito **"Extraer"**, a veces está escrito descomprimir directamente.

Comment: @Joze no sé qué quieres decir con "el menos peor". *Eliminar*, *borrar* y *remover* son claros. En cambio, si yo presiono un botón que dice *Extraer*, lo que menos espero es que se elimine lo que seleccioné.

Comment: @rsanchez hmmmm Sí a fin de cuentas estoy de acuerdo. Pienso que remover es un mejor término.

Answer (score 4):

Se me ocurre:

> YYY ha sido removido correctamente.

Depende en concreto sobre que se este hablando, pero quizás puedes utilizar 'descartado' o 'suprimido'.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Nótese sin embargo que busco un nombre, no un participio. ¿Cuál podría ser el nombre asociado a "remover"? ¿"removimiento"?

Comment: Según la RAE, remover sólo se usa como eliminar en ciertos ámbitos, y probablemente como anglicismo. El sentido de remover es agitar o mezclar algo. Es un *false friend*

Comment: @169134 puédese usarlo para significar quitar u obviar, aunque depende del dialecto, tal significado será muy infrecuente. Pero para tales significados, no hay una eliminación de la cosa, sino un traslado o mudanza. Pero estoy de acuerdo que en este contexto sonaría más como anglicismo para muchos hablantes.

Comment: Fedorqui: *remoción* es el sustantivo correspondiente de *remover*. Según el DPD, el sentido de "quitar" o "apartar" ya estaba presente en el étimo latino, por lo que no hay problema en usarlo en este ámbito.

Comment: @Yay *removimiento* también existe.  El DRAE les da la misma definición (excepto que *remoción* puede también significar en contextos legales la privación de un cargo o empleo)

Comment: @Yay ¡gracias! Nótese por cierto que para mencionar a alguien debes utilizar la arroba antes de su nombre. De lo contrario no se recibe notificación.

Answer (score -1):

Sinónimo de inserción =

> integración

Antónimos:

> Desintegración, separación